# How to use "action" property of swing component in NetBeans GUI builder?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

There is "action" property of many swing components (like JButton, JMenuItem etc) in the property window of NetBeans GUI builder. It displays "none" by default and there is "down arrow" button near it, but when pressed the list of actions to assign is empty. So the question is - how to add some actions to the project to appear in this list? The only way I found is to create some action (i.e. AbstractAction) by hand in the code and then assign it to the component with "custome code" property editor, but obviously it is not convinient.